# Bukkit runnable tips

Tags: java, runnable, bukkit

Hello any ideas how to make scheduleSyncDelayedTask so it doesnt cancel previous task, which should be running and canceled a bit later?

```
for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
    int taskID = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Main.getPlugin(), new Runnable() {        
        @Override
        public void run() {                 
            CreateItems.createItemsOnStand2(player, bedna, listitems);      
        }
    }, 30*x , 2+x);

    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Main.getPlugin(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(taskID);
        }
    }, (x==0) ? 30 : 30*x);     
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? Right now, it looks like you have 2 tasks being created, the latter cancelling the former. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Basically I want to shedule several tasks at different starting time, which should be cancelled accordingly. But currently when first scheduleSyncDelayedTask hits its timer it just completely stops other scheduleSyncRepeatingTask, i guess its because a taskID is being reassigned to new ones, so i am asking if there is a way to shedule many tasks and stop them using scheduleSyncDelayedTask later on.

Comment: Are you sure this code is compiling alright? From what I can see, you should be getting a compiler error about taskID not being final.

Comment: I am using Java 8 and its compiling fine, since i am not changing anything apart from "timers" which is ok to change.

Comment: Why are you canceling repeating tasks during the same tick at which they are scheduled to run for the first time? Your code will run the repeating task scheduled at x = 0 approximately 15 times, since it runs every 2 ticks and is canceled after 30 ticks. Every task scheduled after that iteration of your for loop however will be canceled after running once, since the delay (30 * x) for x > 0 is the same for both the repeating and delayed task. If you only want those tasks to run once, you can use a delayed non-repeating task.

Comment: Ye, I figured that out, now it works, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BukkitRunnables for task scheduling

```
new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Code you need running
        this.cancel();    //Cancelling
    }
}.runTaskTimer(pluginInstance, delayTime, repeatingTime);



 new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Code you need running
        this.cancel();    //Cancelling
    }
}.runTaskLater(pluginInstance, delayTime);
```

It makes it so the task can be easily created and self-cancellable